# Delegate doesn't work using present() and dismiss()

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm trying to pass data from modal VC to parent VC using delegate. 
This is the way I show second VC:

```
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Stations", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StationsVC")
    let stations = StationsVC()
    stations.delegate = self
    present(vc, animated: true)
```

It has a delegate:

```
weak var delegate: SelectedStationDelegate?
```

Which is pretty simple:

```
protocol SelectedStationDelegate: class {
    func setSelectedStation(name: String, color: UIColor)
}
```

Second VC sends data when I dismiss it:

```
private func sendSelectedStation(for indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! StationCell

        guard let selectedStationName = cell.label.text else { return }
        guard let selectedStationColor = cell.circleView.backgroundColor else { return }

        dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.delegate?.setSelectedStation(name: selectedStationName, color: selectedStationColor)
        }
    }
}
```

I thought maybe it doesn't capture any information, but it does — at least breakpoint says so.

And first VC should accept it and change label's text and view's color:

```
extension MapVC: SelectedStationDelegate {

    func setSelectedStation(name: String, color: UIColor) {
        fromLabel.text = name
        print(name)
        print(fromLabel.text!)
        fromCircle.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```

But as you guessed — it doesn't. This function never executes. What is the problem? I suppose it's because of present()'ing and dismiss()'ing, but I couldn't find any information about using delegation without segues or navigation controllers at all :(

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is you are setting delegate to one instance of view controller and presenting another.

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Stations", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StationsVC") as! StationsVC
vc.delegate = self
present(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Stations", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StationsVC") //you are creating second vc
let stations = StationsVC() //also creating another second vc, remove this line
stations.delegate = self
present(vc, animated: true)
```

use @Sanket Bhavsar Answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you are creating two instances of view controller

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Stations", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StationsVC") //here
let stations = StationsVC() // here
stations.delegate = self
present(vc, animated: true)
```

second you are not presenting `stations` that you have assigned delegate but you are presenting controller which is `vc` which you have not  assigned delegate and

if you present your `station` controller it might crash your application as all the outlet will not be initialised(if you have given).

so if you are using storyboards and outlets then use this

```
guard let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Stations", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StationsVC") as? StationsVC else {return}
vc.delegate = self
present(vc, animated: true)
```

and if you are using only programming to create view controllers than

```
let stations = StationsVC() // here
stations.delegate = self
present(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Yep, great answer, thank you. Although you're about crashing — it crashes without guard construction but doesn't even open with it. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: thanks you if you find it helpful you can approve it

Comment: it crashes without guard statement because it wont be able to find storyboard id or can't cast it as your class so in guard statement when it wont find storyboard id or can't cast it as your class then it will execute else part and return from functions and it wont execute any other statement so your `present`method will not be called

Comment: StationsVC is embedded into UINavigationController, so the problem is in it. This code: 
        guard let vc = (UIStoryboard(name: "Stations", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StationsVC") as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? StationsVC else { return }
        vc.delegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true)

Also doesn't help, it only causes an error 'Application tried to present modally an active controller'. Am I casting it right?

Comment: you are presenting it twice thats why this error is happening

Comment: Found a problem, I had to present navigationController, but set delegate to StationsVC. Thank you, it finally works!

Answer (score 1):

```
You have created two instances for StationVC class.

let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Stations", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StationsVC") // First Instance
let stations = StationsVC() // Second Instance-- remove this line of code
```

Try to use this line of code:

```
let stationVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Stations", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StationsVC") as! StationsVC
stationVC.delegate = self


By doing this, your delegates will call
```